# Probability density function of $x s$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability density function of scalar $x$ is given by
$$Pr(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},x\geq0$$
One needs to find a probability density function of $x\cdot s$ where s is just a vector of scalar values (deterministic values). If $s$ was just one scalar value instead of being a vector of scalars the probability should be (correct me if i am wrong)
$$Pr_0(x)=s_0\lambda e^{-\lambda x s_0 },x\geq0$$
where $s_0$ is just some real scalar value. Would the probability of $s$ being a vector be the product $Pr_0(x)$ for each constant in vector $s$ divided by the number of the components in vector $s$?

Answer (score 1):

Think of $xs$ as just another element of the sample space. The density value for $xs_0$ is $Pr(xs_0)=\lambda e^{-\lambda xs_0},xs_0\geq 0$.

For the second part, the probability of $\vec{s}$ as a vector is not well defined since it is a constant not a random element. If $\vec{s}=(s_1,s_2,...,s_n)$, then $Pr(x\vec{s})=(Pr(xs_1),Pr(xs_2),...,Pr(xs_n))$ with each component defined as above.